# Why is the image and label not loading the imported information?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am importing an image and string from parse and putting it within a cell, but it does not load into the view, when I go to another view and come back, it appears. Any reason why this is happening and how do I fix it? Notice I am calling this in the viewDidLoad.

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if(error == nil){

                for object in objects!{
                   if let name = object["Animal"] as? PFObject{
                        self.animalname.append(name["Name"] as! String)
                        self.tableview.reloadData()

                    }

                    if let pic = object["Animal"]["Pic"] as? PFFile{
                        pic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            if(error == nil){
                                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                                self.imagepro.append(image!)


                            }

                        })
                        self.tableview.reloadData()
                    }
            }
      }
```

Comment: The picture loads in the background too, so you will have to reload the tableView when it completes. You also seem to be storing the picture in `imagepro`, but how are you going to guarantee you get the right picture for the right cell given they might run in any order? Also, reloadData should be called on the main queue using `dispatch_async`.

Comment: UPDATE* when I try to access the pointers name nothing happens

Comment: What's the pointer? Can you post your code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? How does it know which animalname and imagepro index to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, you're reloading your table view, before the image downloads. Try this

```
if let pic = object["Animal"]["Pic"] as? PFFile{
    pic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if(error == nil){
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.imagepro.append(image!)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                 self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```